# pip install not working inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I have created a small project in flask and I am trying to deploy it using docker. For this I have created my Dockerfile that looks like following:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app 
ADD . /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

# run the command to start uWSGI
CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

My requirements.txt file contains the following:

```
#click==7.1.1
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
uWSGI==2.0.18
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

I tried to build my project using docker-build with --network=host option and also usingdocker-compose, but have not been successful. I get the following error:

```
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fac273160f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fac27316588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fac27316828>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fac273166a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fac273168d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask==1.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

I have no clue why  I am getting this error. Can somebody help me with this? I am running docker-compose build command inside python virtual environment.

Comment: for python3 it is called pip3

Comment: What is the proxy for? Can you connect to the proxy from inside the container and host?

Comment: @AndyShinn I did not have them at first and yet it gave me the same error. Then I searched internet and tried it and saw a recommendation to use it. Hence I used it. It still shows the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I had to create a file /etc/docker/daemon.json and add the following section:

```
{
  "dns": ["myDNS"]
}
```

The value of myDNS was obtained using the following:

```
nmcli dev show | grep 'DNS'
```

After that I restarted my docker and was able to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your container can't connect to the internet while installing pip, so you need to fix this. I assume removing proxy from your docker file should fix this.

Comment: I did not have them at first and yet it gave me the same error. Then I searched internet and tried it and saw a recommendation to use it. Hence I used it. Yet I get the same error even I have removed them

Comment: I was not able to edit my previous comment. I just wanted to clarify that the problem is not installing pip but installing dependencies using pip inside Dockerfile.

Comment: Please then remove proxy from your config and add proper error, cause now I see "Cannot connect to proxy" what is obvious that proxy is not working

Comment: I have remove the proxy configurations and updated the error.

Comment: Again you do not have internet connection from your container. What is host for this container? Probably you are missing iptables rules. Try to get fresh droplet on digital ocean and just install docker there and then it should work. Problem is in your docker host most likely

Answer (score 0):

Spent all day trying to figure this out with `npm ci` only on my UI, then tested backend and it happened there too with `pip install`. I was then prompted by docker for an update so did that, then that failed. Then docker suggested I restore to defaults. Did that and problem fixed.